# How can I stop the idle chatter from NPCs in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> *I work with my mother, to sell fruits and vegetables. It's fun most days, but hard work.*

I am SO tired of hearing this line and countless others whenever I walk by someone. I've taken to avoiding people in Skyrim just so that they won't stop and tell me who they are, what they're doing, and why they're doing it, every time I get within six feet of them. Is there some way to stop NPCs from doing this (an option, mod *or* other non-mod solutions), enabling me to walk right past them without being interrupted?

Comment: Hey Thomas; I'm glad you found an answer. However, for future reference, questions of this type are considered off-topic (see the close reason for more details). We prefer for this kind of question to be asked in [chat]. Thanks for understanding :)

Comment: Hi Schism. Sorry about that; my main presence is over on Writers SE, so I didn't know what's on and off topic over here. I probably should have checked that out before I asked.

Comment: I've reworded the question to not ask specifically for a mod recommendation, and to ask for any solution instead. Voting to reopen as per the meta posts: […looking for mods for specific purposes](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11578/4797) "*Give us the actual problem… and we'll solve that, and if the solution involves a mod, so be it*", and [Closed 'mod recommendation' Skyrim question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5547/4797) "*This is not a shopping recommendation (a request for subjective… advice). The problem can be clearly stated and objectively evaluated in most cases.*"

Comment: @ThomasMyron This is *not* off-topic as per the community discussions I've linked in my comment above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you want the ["No NPC Greetings" mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/746/?), also available on the [Steam Workshop](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=7431).

It's pretty easy to find such mods by just Googling, or browsing Nexus Mods, in case you might want more in the future.

Comment: Also, if you don't want to completely remove it and just lower the frequency of the greetings, you can use the ["Less Talkative NPCs" mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/1928/?). Just as a different option for other people.

Comment: Actually, that mod has three different versions that lower the space required to initiate conversation, so it's quite customizable.